# Please help identify this 1980's, very odd, Non-Lego brick!

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I have one more mystery brick to share, and it is a strange one.  This brick is FIVE studs long, and the width is comparable to a regular 2x4 Lego brick.  The inner tubes are also comparable, but because of the slope, the brick's length is five studs.

This brick was included in a large lot of early 1980's bricks.  It doesn't have the Lego name anywhere that I can see.  Could it be possibly a Tyco part?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 2x5, heaven forbid!

Comment: To me it looks like the [air-box of Ferrari Formula 1 car](http://i.imgur.com/o0yTXu5.jpg) (the part behind the drivers head). It doesn't seem to match any of the parts used in the official LEGO Ferrari sets.

Comment: This brick does not appear in the [BrickLink](https://www.bricklink.com) catalog for [2x5 parts](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=2x5) or [5x2 parts](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=5x2). Therefore I seriously doubt it is genuine Lego.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had to tell for sure, but it looks like it came from the red car in this Mega Bloks set:

http://blokcity.com/wiki/9801_Build_%26_Race_Speedway

Here's an image including that part from this set:

[image: Mega 9801 red car parts]

Comment: That looks right to me. I added the best image I could find of that part in that set.